# Getting access violation error while using %s in scanf_s

Tags: c, windows, scanf

I am a beginner and I am learning C and using Visual Studio Code 2019 and I get an error like this:

```
Exception thrown at 0x7C97E63C (ucrtbased.dll) in string.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00900000".
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() {
    char str[50];

    scanf_s("%s", &str);

    printf("%s", str);

    return 0;
}
```

I know it is a very noob type question but when I compile the same code with Code::Blocks, it runs fine but ultimately I have to use VScode to build projects so I am stuck here. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did the compiler give you any warnings about the data type expected by `%s`? Also, when you ran the program, what did you enter before it faulted?

Comment: I think you need a char pointer type: char*.

Comment: You're calling `scanf_s` incorrectly.  For a `%s` specifier, you need to pass a `char *` argument (which you also aren't - remove the `&` operator), and the count (which you aren't).  And turn on compiler warnings.  Your compiler should have complained about both errors.

Comment: The program built up successfully and there was no compiler error and not even any warning actually the error arrives at run time when i run the program and the input was like "hello world" as i am taking a string as input

Comment: scanf_s() is designed to intentionally crash the program when you use it wrong.  The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019) have an explicit example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior because you do not pass the size argument `scanf_s` expects after the destination pointer for the `%s` conversion.  Furthermore, you should pass `str`, not `&str` although that should not cause a problem.  You should also test if `scanf_s` succeeds to avoid calling `printf` with an uninitialized array if it fails, for example if the input stream is an empty file.

Finally, there is a problem with `scanf_s` that is well beyond your current skill level: this function is defined with different semantics on Windows and in the C Standard, so the way you can pass the size argument depends on the compiler.

For standard complying compilers, such as `gcc` and `clang` in linux and Mac/OS, you would use `sizeof str` which has type `size_t`, but on Windows you must cast this as `(unsigned)` because Microsoft's version of `scanf_s` expects this type, which has a different size on 64-bit systems. For this and other reasons, `scanf_s` should not be used in a portable program.

Here is a modified version for linux and Mac/OS:

```c
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() {
    char str[50];

    if (scanf("%49s", str) == 1) {
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a modified version for Windows, where the compiler insists on the use of `scanf_s` with non-standard semantics:

```c
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() {
    char str[50];

    if (scanf_s("%49s", str, (unsigned)sizeof(str)) == 1) {
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The `49` in `%49s` prevents `scanf_s` from triggering an implementation defined exception.

Comment: thanks a lot guys for your responses and i am getting the  mistake a  bit. As i told you i am a beginner so i am implementing it in my code.. and then i will give my feedback   thanks a lot.

Comment: yes you said it right scanf_s is beyond my skill level so what should you all suggest to me? should i use code blocks or just stick with this visual studio code.

Comment: @VishalSingh: I did not imply that `scanf_s` is beyond your skill level, but that the subtle portability issue between Windows and Standard C versions of `scanf_s` is. 
 `scanf` or `scanf_s` are probably part of your curriculum, so you should study how these functions work. They are quite cumbersome and quirky, very often misused. To read a line of input, use `fgets()`.